# Function is increasing - mathematical formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

So I have a few tasks like this one from the title:

Function is increasing <- write the mathematical formula corresponding to the following statement

I am not sure of the notation I should use. Is it

$∀x,y\;\; x < y : f(x) < f(y)$

or

$\forall x,y ((x < y) \to  (f(x) < f(y)))$

Or are both solutions fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $$\forall x,y \; [x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)]$$ is sometimes written more compactly as $$\forall x < y \; [f(x) < f(y)].$$ Both of those are shorthand for $$\forall x \; \forall y \; [x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)].$$

Comment: Also, If one to formalize this statement in full, it’s desired to mention the domain of a function: $$\forall x,y\in\operatorname{dom}f\;[x<y\implies f(x) < f(y)].$$ Or without shorthands as e. g. $$\forall x\;\forall y\;[\{x,y\}\subset\operatorname{dom}f\wedge x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)].$$[When one works at a level of formal set theory, this is absolutely needed, as there $f(x)$ would be defined even for $x\notin\operatorname{dom}f$ (taking some dummy value like $\varnothing$), unless the logic used allows non-everywhere defined terms, which it usually doesn’t.]

Comment: I certainly agree. Good comment to make! Thanks.

Comment: @arseniiv If $f$ is a function symbol in a single-sorted logic, then there is no need or even way to state what its domain is as a formula. In the multi-sorted case, you'd simply need to specify the sorts of the variables and those would need to match the sort of the function symbol, but this would be a well-formedness check, again, not something that would or could be stated as a formula. Nothing about the question suggests that it is taking place in a set-theoretic context or that $f$ is a set-theoretic function.

Comment: @DerekElkins You’re of course right, except I doubt the question is stated as to prefer one context to another—there’s simply not enough told IMHO. I admit a context where $f$ is a functional constant/variable didn’t come to my mind earlier.